# Prevent text from moving when resizing css

Tags: html, css

With a colleague of mine, we wanted to run a behavioural experiment that involve a fake purchase of virtual goods on a shop webpage. We designed the experiment on OTree (so on Python), but we needed Django and especially some html/css code to correctly place the images and texts on the webpage.

We managed to place the images and text as we wanted, to get something like that (the blue squares are just placeholders for the images): [image]

The problem is that as soon as we change the window size, all the images and text just move on their own.

Here's a part of the code (not including everything because for now, we're just trying to get first the text in place and to understand the logic of it).

Here's the CSS:

```
    <style>
 body {
     background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lVtlHWx.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
</style>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div style="top: 99px; left: 99px;position: absolute; z-index: 1;visibility: visible;">
<h1 style="position: relative; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;">Welcome to the shop</h1>
<h3 style="position: relative;color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;">Round 1/10</h3>

<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:6.5cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">5 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:18cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">15 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:29.5cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">25 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:41cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">50 Rubis</p>

<p style="position: relative;top:16cm; left:6.5cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">5 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:18cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">15 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:29.5cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">25 Rubis</p>
<p style="position: relative;top:9.5cm; left:41cm; color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Papyrus,monospace;font-size:25px;">50 Rubis</p>
```

We're complete beginners in HTML/CSS and I think we bite more than we could chew. I followed and tried some answers but nothing really helped to resize every element with respect to the window size. Perhaps it is due to positioning the text? I still struggle to really understand how css places elements when their position are absolute or relative. We are in dire need of help on this matter, and would be immensely grateful if someone could solve our issue.

Comment: Use flexbox it will make this much easier. Also look into using bootstrap. It’s easier than it looks

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll check that!

Comment: @Jauhnax That was fun to do, but it's a horrible way of laying out html! You should be using different textures for your wood-like background and iron-looking frames, and design the page with html in a more adaptable way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case where using a table or better, CSS grid positioning would save you a lot of headaches.

Positioning according to measurements on your background image gives the following:

```css
:root {
  --display-scale: .5;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden; /* disable scrolling */
}

.wrapper {
  transform: scale(var(--display-scale));
  -webkit-transform: scale(var(--display-scale));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 1884px;
  height: 1076px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/lVtlHWx.png') no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Papyrus, monospace;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.wrapper * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.wrapper h3 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.wrapper .wallet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  height: 46px;
  left: 720px;
  right: 682px;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper .my-grid {
  position: absolute;
  /*background: #ff000055;*/
  top: 228px;
  left: 110px;
  right: 82px;
  bottom: 82px;
  padding: 0;
  column-gap: 38px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 384px 402px 406px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 196px 50px 202px 50px 202px 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.my-grid .prod-image {
  /*background: #00ff0055;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.my-grid img {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #5555ff;
  outline: 5px solid black;
}

.my-grid .price {
  /*background: #0000ff55;*/
  font-size: 24px;
  margin 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Welcome to the shop</h1>
  <h3>Round 1/10</h3>
  <p class="wallet">You have 1000 tokens</p>
  <div class="my-grid">
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">5 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">15 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">25 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">5 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">15 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">25 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
    <div class="prod-image"><img class="pic" /></div>
    <p class="price">50 Rubis</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the `--display-scale: .5` variable to adjust display size

Comment: Just notice scale doesn't work on Chrome ! fixing that

Comment: Fixed this issue with css variable and -webkit- prefix!

Comment: Incredible, thank you immensely for your answer! Do you think it's possible to add a black background (around the shop) and to prevent the scrolling down (I can scroll down but there is nothing)? If it's not possible, it's fine, you already truly helped me.

Comment: Disable scrolling with "overflow: hidden;" on the container that you want to remove scrolling on.

Comment: Thank you, to both of you. You just saved my colleague's life and mine aha!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired results with css [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

This page content:

```html
<body>
    <div id="head">
        <h1>Welcome to the shop</h1>
        <h3>Round 1/10</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="labels_container">
        <div class="item"><p class="label">5 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">15 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">25 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">50 Rubis</p></div>

        <div class="item"><p class="label">5 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">15 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">25 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">50 Rubis</p></div>

        <div class="item"><p class="label">5 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">15 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">25 Rubis</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p class="label">50 Rubis</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

With this css styling:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('./lVtlHWx.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    display: grid;

    grid-template-rows: [gstart]1fr[gmid] 5fr[gend];
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#head {
    grid-row: gstart / gmid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#head * {
    margin: 0;
}

#labels_container {
    grid-row: gmid / gend;


    margin-top: 3vh;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 7vw;
    margin-bottom: 9.5vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2.5%;
}
.item .label {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
* {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family: Papyrus, monospace;
}

h1, h3 {
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.label {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

should do what you want.

Note: You might also find it beneficial to make the interface a div in your page with a constant aspect ratio, because you have an image as the backdrop for the entire interface. Having this image deform makes styling the page awkward. That being said, the styles above should work with your current setup.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help! I'll try that immediatly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the text is still moving, but I think that's just an impression and that's only due to the background image https://imgur.com/a/oz9hREY.

Comment: Can you link the full html/css of the site (perhaps on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or in a GitHub Gist? That is very strange.
[This is how it appears for me](https://imgur.com/a/yqCHW2n).
Here is an [all-in-one html file](https://gist.github.com/John-Paul-R/a1119c6998b82cb89d47637a36e7721b) (includes both html and css) that you can try.

Comment: I think it's due to Django and OTree code that have their own css styles, which is conflicting with your code. Removing them solved the issue, but I ignore if Django variables will still be able to be used then. Here's the code https://pastebin.com/GU02De1c

Comment: I have, to the best of my ability, edited your file to keep the existing structure, while laying the visual content out properly, although some of the html in your original file is malformed, so I had to guess at your intentions a tiny bit. [Here is my best attempt.](https://gist.github.com/John-Paul-R/0254ef013677c773f93004f2697248b0)
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist, here is what you should really do: abandon your backdrop that constrains layout, and use a real HTML layout instead, with textures to help achieving the effect you want.

*This snippet should be viewed in full page mode*

```css
:root {
  --iron-texture: url('https://www.outworldz.com/SeamlessTextures/master/Metal/iron_diffuse.png');
  --wood-texture: url('https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/22092207/Seamless-Wooden-Floor-Texture.jpg?width=600');
}

html { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%;}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Papyrus, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shop {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background: var(--wood-texture);
  background-size: 30%;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.shop header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.shop h1,
.shop p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.shop h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.shop .round {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.iron-style {
  background: var(--iron-texture);
  border: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-top-color: #2a2a2a;
  border-right-color: #2a2a2a;
}

.shop .wallet {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20em;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

.shop main {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem 1rem;
  border: 1rem solid #222;
  border-image: var(--iron-texture);
  border-image-repeat: round;
  border-image-slice: 20;
  box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 3px #111,
              inset 3px -3px 5px #333;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pic-layout {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pic-layout img {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: #aaf;
  outline: 5px solid #333;
}

.price {
  width: 6em;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .shop main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .shop main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .shop .round {
    position: static;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="shop">
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to the Shop</h1>
    <p class="round">Round 1/10</p>
    <p class="wallet iron-style">You have 1000 tokens</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="product" id="product-1">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods1/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">5 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-2">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods2/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">25 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-3">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods3/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">15 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-4">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods4/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">42 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-5">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods5/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">120 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-6">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods6/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">33 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-7">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods7/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">6 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-8">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods8/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">44 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-9">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods9/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">99 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-10">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods10/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">1 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-11">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods11/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">23 Rubis</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="product-12">
      <div class="pic-layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/prods12/150/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="price iron-style">16 Rubis</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
```

This time I structured the shop with one wrapper div per product, but I could have avoided that using the same kind of grid as in my previous answer.

There are no vertical separators as CSS `grid` does not allow for inner borders (yet). If this is a requirement, the `<main>` element should be replaced with a `<table>`, which allows for all kinds of borders.

`grid` has the advantage of offering responsive layout using `@media` queries. That's why you can see all products on only 2 columns in the sample above, unless you enlarge it to full page.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing, thank you so much for your help!